# Symfony/Doctrine Shared Entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like to create a `Note` entity in my Symfony project that can be used with multiple other entities. For example, it could be used to leave a comment about a **product** or a comment about a **supplier** or a comment about an **order**. These will be much like the User Contributed Notes in the PHP manual.

All my entities have an integer ID and so I thought the best way to implement this would be to have `ownerId` and `ownerType` fields on the note. The `ownerId` would be set to the product's ID, the supplier's ID or the order's ID. The `ownerType` would be set to the entity name.

In any entity that I wanted to have notes attached to (e.g., **product**, **supplier**, **order**, etc.) I would add:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity="Note", mappedBy="ownerId" )
 */
private $notes;

public function addNote( $n ) {
    if( !$this->notes->contains( $n ) ) {
        $this->notes[] = $n;
        $n->setProduct( $this );
    }
}
```

In the note I would have have:

```
public function setOwner( $o ) {
    $this->ownerId = $o->getId();
    $this->ownerType = get_class( $o );
}
public function setProduct( $p ) {
    $this->setOwner( $p );
}
public function setSupplier( $s ) {
    $this->setOwner( $s );
}
public function setOrder( $o ) {
    $this->setOwner( $o );
}
```

It creates problems because there is no **owning side** field or the **owning side field is not an association** or, if I create one, its target entity is wrong, etc.

Is there any way to implement this structure using Symfony and Doctrine? I really don't want to have to have **ProductNote**, **SupplierNote**, **OrderNote**, etc., etc., etc., tables and all the duplicated code.

Answer (score 2):

What you looking for is [Doctrine inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html). With this you will create Note model as abstract and then create ProductNote, SupplierNote and etc just like simple entities (will by just class and `@Entity` annotation).

For you use case (because you have same structure for everything) I would go for single table inheritance which is using one table and will not have performance impact.

Then in your child classes (for example ProductNote) you will have just `setOwner` which will accept concrete object and you can map one field for all child entities.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand the documentation correctly I will have a `Note` super class with id, noteText, ownerId, and ownerType properties. My `@DiscriminatorColumn` will be ownerType. The child classes will extend `Note` but not have any properties themselves. Their ownerType will automagically be set when `new ProductNote;` is called. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it. Note doesn't have to be super class, can be normal just defined as abstract. And exactly after then you will be creating instances of ProductNote, ContributorNote and etc.